# nginx/gunicorn throwing 504s (time outs) after some time - how to debug?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

We have a nginx - gunicorn - django setup.

Server runs fine for a while and then nginx starts throwing 
**504 Gateway Time-outs**.
*Trying to access gunicorn locally (127.0.0.1:8000) with lynx does not work either.*

Logging into the machine shows enough cpu, memory and disc space available:

```
CPU[||||                                                             3.3%]
Mem[||||||||||||||||||                                         362/3750MB]

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  5.5G  2.1G  73% /
```

Supervisor shows gunicorn is running:

```
gunicorn                         RUNNING    pid 25264, uptime 2 days, 8:55:22
```

The database that sits underneath django is alive.
I looked through the django, supervisor, nginx and database logs and I couldn't find anything (!) suspicious.

**[Update: Logs]**

In the nginx.error.logs there is a few

```
client intended to send too large body
SSL_do_handshake() failed
```

errors every now and then and for sure

```
upstream timed out
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

errors after gunicorn got stuck.

**Versions**

```
nginx/1.6.2
gunicorn==18.0
Django==1.6.2
supervisor==3.0
```

Any recommendations how to find out what/why that's happening?

*(restarting gunicorn via supervisor fixes the issue)*

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG=True`?  If so, Django stores every single SQL query it runs in memory.  Looks like you have plenty of memory left, but maybe there's a constraint somewhere you're running into?

Comment: DEBUG is set to False.

Comment: Did you look at /var/log/gunicorn log files? Is anything relevant there?

Comment: Not that I can see. I have a few errors on the db, but they happen when the system is healthy too. The db is definitely alive and working.

Comment: I upgraded to gunicorn==19.3.0 about a month ago and it didn't happen anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [504 error when the view loading takes more than 5 s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364196/504-error-when-the-view-loading-takes-more-than-5-s)